# Parallelogram -diagonal-similarity problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a parallelogram $ABCD$ . Points $M$ and $N$ are respectively the midpoints of $BC$ and $CD$ .
Lengths $AM$ and $AN$ intersecting diagonal $BD$ consecutive points $P$ and $Q$.
Prove that triangles $AQB$ I $NQD$ are similar and find the coefficient of similarity .
Prove that the length of $BP$ , $PQ$ and $QD$ equal length .

My work: If triangle $AQB$ I $NQD$ are similar then we know:
$$\frac{AQ}{NQ}=\frac{AB}{ND}=\frac{QB}{QD}=k$$
$$k=\frac{AB}{ND}=\frac{CD}{ND}=\frac{2ND}{ND}=2$$
By the diagonal $BD$ we have 1 equal angle $\angle QBA=\angle QDN $

Comment: A diagram of the situation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If triangle $AQB$ I $NQD$ are similar then

We have to prove that $\triangle{AQB}$ and $NQD$ are similar, so you cannot start with that.

---

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Since $CD$ is parallel to $BA$, we have
$$\angle{QAB}=\angle{QND}\quad\text{and}\quad \angle{QBA}=\angle{QDN}$$
from which the claim follows with $QB:QD=AB:ND=2:1$.

Similarly, we can prove that $\triangle{APD}$ and $\triangle{MPB}$ are similar with $DP:BP=AD:MB=2:1$.

Thus, we can write
$$BP=a,\quad DP=2a,\quad DQ=b,\quad QB=2b$$
From $BD=3a=3b\Rightarrow a=b$, we have $BP=PQ=QD$.